# Given the function $f(x) =|x-1|$ in $\mathbb{R}$, I’m asked to find its primitive function.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, absolute-value

Given the function $f(x) =|x-1|$ in $\mathbb{R}$, I’m asked to find its primitive function.

***My Attempt:***

$$\int|x-1|dx=\begin{array}{c}
\int(x-1)dx\ \ \text{if  }x\ge1\\
\int(-x+1)dx\ \ \text{if  }x<1
\end{array} $$

Therefore: $$\int|x-1|dx=\begin{array}{c}
\frac{x^{2}}{2}-x+c\ \text{  if  } x\ge1\\
-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x+c\ \text{ if  }x<1
\end{array}$$

My problem is that if you look on the interval in $[1,1.5]$, for instance, you’ll get that the integral is negative. Given that we know that if a function is non-negative in some interval, then the function’s integral in that interval is also non-negative, it seems that my primitive function is false as it does not obtain this property.

The primitive function I found contradicts that theorem, but I don’t understand in which part I was wrong integrating the function.

Comment: Start with finding the primitive of |x| then shift 1 unit to the right

Comment: Are you familiar with finding the primitive of a piecewise defined function?

Comment: @1123581321 this is what I did, started by finding the primitive of $|x|$, but why the function shifts to the right? I don't get that part

Comment: @Keen-ameteur yes i do

Comment: The definite integral would be non-negative, which you would obtain by the Newton-Leibnitz formula. By your reasoning $1$ doesn't have non-negtive integral on an interval. I think despite solving it problematically you've arrived at a right answer.